# Can't load a custom template through getChildHtml

Tags: magento-1.8, rwd, local.xml, header

I'm using Magento 1.8.1 with lots of changes (difficult to update) and I would like to introduce the 1.9 rwd top menu for mobiles to my website because it's really interesting.
The way I want to do it is to add on my header.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('rwdtopMenu'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('rwdtopSearch'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('rwdtopAccount'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('rwdtopCart'); ?>
```

and hide it via css with `display:none` when window width is lesser than a specific value.


A part from this, I've also added to my local.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="rwdtopMenu" as="rwdtopMenu" template="rwdmenu/rwdtopmenu.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="rwdtopSearch" as="rwdtopSearch" template="rwdmenu/rwdtopsearch.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="rwdtopAccount" as="rwdtopAccount" template="rwdmenu/rwdtopaccount.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="rwdtopCart" as="rwdtopCart" template="rwdmenu/rwdtopcart.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

And in the location `default/mytheme/template/rwdmenu` I've created the file `rwdtopmenu.phtml` with some testing text on it.

```
<p>Some testing text</p>
```

But it displays nothing and I don't know why it could be. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reference block name is wrong.It should be `header` (`<reference name="header">)`  instead of `root`  **(** `<reference name="root">` **)**.

***getChildHtml()*** loads `the HTML for the child block with the name` which is passed to the method.

> ```
> <default>
>     <reference name="header">
>         <block type="core/template" name="rwdtopMenu" as="rwdtopMenu" template="rwdmenu/rwdtopmenu.phtml"/>
>     </reference>
>     <reference name="header">
>         <block type="core/template" name="rwdtopSearch" as="rwdtopSearch" template="rwdmenu/rwdtopsearch.phtml"/>
>     </reference>
>     <reference name="header">
>         <block type="core/template" name="rwdtopAccount" as="rwdtopAccount" template="rwdmenu/rwdtopaccount.phtml"/>
>     </reference>
>     <reference name="header">
>         <block type="core/template" name="rwdtopCart" as="rwdtopCart" template="rwdmenu/rwdtopcart.phtml"/>
>     </reference>
> </default>
> ```

Get More  details getChildHtml().Checkout below link:

[Understanding getChildHtml in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488885/understanding-getchildhtml-in-magento)

Comment: You should also reference the header block only once

Comment: Awesome, it worked.
@Alex I had it in one root at the begining but as this didn't work I tried different ways with no succeed either. 
Now it's set up to one header only working perfect. Thank you both!